# Detailed running time analysis for Shamir secret sharing scheme

Tags: secret-sharing, reference-request, complexity, resources

I am successfully working on Shamir's secret sharing scheme for few months. But the only issue I am facing is the calculation of theoretical time complexity.

Since I am from algorithmic background, I am unaware of the time complexities of the cryptographic operations. Although I found a [question that discuss about running times of cryptographic primitive operations](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6164/how-do-i-derive-the-time-complexity-of-encryption-and-decryption-based-on-modula), I cannot able to figure out the exact running time analysis for myself since it involves details that I am not sure about.

In my search on running time for Shamir's secret sharing scheme, I found a question discussing that: [Running time of Shamir's secret sharing scheme](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33240/running-time-of-shamirs-secret-sharing-scheme).

But the answers provided are not providing much analysis in detail i.e., step-wise manner nor providing any reference that performs step by step analysis. I personally did not find any material over internet that calculates running time of the Shamir's secret sharing scheme like the [analysis for insertion sort provided in page no: 4 of the lecture](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1168/lecture1.pdf).

Henceforth, please provide me any reference material that performs running time analysis of Shamir's secret sharing scheme or please provide such analysis as an answer, if possible.